# Experimental determination of moments of inertia of a vehicle

Tags: kinematics, moment-of-inertia

I need to experimentally determine the moments of inertia ( $ I_{xx} $ and $ I_{yy}$) of a small all terrain vehicle and compare it to the values obtained from CAD software.

I am really struggling to find decent resources that deal with complex objects .  They typically use a pendulum method, but that requires suspending a 500kg mass on a rope about its centre of gravity (which is in empty space and not on the structure itself)

Is there a universally accepted method to do this?  Are there perhaps resources that you have come across that could help?

Comment: -1 for lack of research effort. Have you tried googling your exact title? Numerous articles are returned, including this one : http://ijj.sagepub.com/content/34/4/291.abstract.

Comment: Read my comments to John Rennie.  As far as I can work out, the article you mentioned uses the method I though John explained (before he added a picture).  I saw the article when searching, but didnt have access to it from my home computer.

Comment: No, the IJMEE article uses a spring for restoring force, not gravity. You can request the full text via [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233683827_Experimental_Determination_of_Moments_of_Inertia_for_an_Off-Road_Vehicle_in_a_Regular_Engineering_Laboratory). Another useful article is [Measuring the Yaw MI of a Vehicle](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/mecdc.2013.11.issue-1/mecdc-2013-0003/mecdc-2013-0003.xml) which also uses a spring. You will also need to find the CG position, eg http://pernerscontacts.upce.cz/41_2015/Hejtmanek.pdf.

Comment: I dont know how I couldnt find something similar.  Most of what I found was behind somesort of paywall or only for small objects.  Those 3 articles are more than enough. Thank you for the help.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pendulum method is probably the easiest and most accurate way to measure the moments of inertia, but you don't need to mess around with ropes through the centre of mass. Just attach a bar to the front (or any convenient part) of your ATV and measure the period of the oscillations using that bar as an axle.

[image: ATV]

This gives you the moment of inertia about that axle, and you then just use the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) to calculate the moment of inerta about the centre of mass. For increased accuracy you could repeat this using a bar fixed to the rear of the vehicle.

It's still not trivial to be hoisting a 500kg ATV around, but my limited experience of engineering students suggests they will have no problem doing an experiment like this.

Comment: What would I need at the other end of the vehicle?  As I understand you, the front is attached to a bar ( that can rotate freely).  The vehicle is then lifted, and then dropped.  What happens to the back end at the end of the drop?  Do you put a couple of springs there and acceleration sensors at the back of the vehicle?

Comment: @22134484 Just let the vehicle pivot about the bar under it's own weight. Time the oscillations to measure the period then use this to get $I$. A quick Google found [this paper explaining the calculation](http://web.mit.edu/8.01t/www/materials/modules/chapter24.pdf). See page 24-3. Or there will be loads more on this out there in Googlespace.

Comment: I understand you now ( I think).  I thought the whole setup was horizontal, to get rid of the effort of suspending the thing from a roof.  Thank you for the help man.

Comment: @22134484 good luck dangling your ATV from a bar :-)

Comment: Polite cough: 500kg, not 500g.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using forced oscillations close to the normal position of the vehicle on the ground. For example, the design may include something like a jack with a rotating cam with a motor, so you could measure the periodic vertical force acting on the vehicle (maybe using some dynamic load cell) and the amplitude of oscillation of the vehicle (using an accelerometer). You could install the jack first at the rear and then at the side of the vehicle to measure different components of the moment of inertia. You should ensure that the wheels opposite the jack are fixed. It is then easy to recalculate the components of the moment of inertia with respect to the center of gravity. I don't know if this method will be accurate enough for you.

At least you won't need to suspend the vehicle.